# Finding a topology doesn't convey Hausdorff property by an injective continuous function

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

Is there a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ that for which , set $A=(0,1)$ be Hausdorff and $B=[0,1]$ not to be Hausdorff with subspace topology and there exist an injective continuous function $f:A \to B$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Consider the topology $\tau$ whose elements are the open subsets of $(0,1)$ (with respect to the usual topology) and the unions of an open subset of $(0,1)$ (again, with respect to the usual topology) with $\mathbb{R}\setminus(0,1)$. Then $(0,1)$, as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$, has its usual topology and therefore it is Hausdorff. But $[0,1]$ isn't, since every open set which contains $0$ also contains $1$ (and vice-versa).

Now, let $f\colon A\longrightarrow B$ be the function defined by $f(x)=x$. It is injective and continuous.

Comment: Aren't $[0,0.5)$ and $(0.5,1]$  two open sets with no intersection seperates $0$ and $1$ ,what is the insejtive continuous function satisfies the conclusion?

Comment: No. None of them is an open set in $[0,1]$ with the subspace topology. Keep in mind that every element of $\tau$ to which $0$ belongs also contains $1$ and vice-versa.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding Somewhere in both the question and the answer, where did you use the function$f$?

Comment: @MasM I've edited my answer. I hope that everything is clear now.

Comment: I have doubt that $\tau$ be a topology,if you consider $(a,b)\in (0,1)$ be the open set chosen to become union of $\mathbb{R}\setminus(0,1)$ constructing set named $O$then $O \bigcap ([0,1]\setminus(a,b))=\{0,1\}$ and these are not in $\tau$

Comment: What do you mean by $(a,b)\in(0,1)$? Did you mean $(a,b)\subset(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, that was mistake thanks for correction ,would you please edit ,it becomed banned after 5 minites

Comment: I cannot edit comments made by others! Anyway, I don't undersatand your problem. Do you claim that $\tau$ is not closed with respect to arbitrary unions? Or that it is not closed with respect to finite intersections?

Comment: The latter one: it is not closed with respect to finite intersections

Comment: @MasM If $A_1,A_2\in\tau$, then each of them is either an open subset of $(0,1)$ (with respect to the usual topology) or the union of an open subset of $(0,1)$ with $\mathbb{R}\setminus(0,1)$ and in each case $A_1\cap A_2\in\tau$. Do you think you can provide a counterexample? Do it!

Comment: The comment 23min ago above is a counterexample,isn't it? $\{0,1\} not in \tau$

Comment: How? $[0,1]\setminus (a,b)\notin\tau$.

Comment: $[0,1]\setminus(a,b)=[0,a]\bigcup[b,1]\in \tau$

Comment: @MasM You seem to be assuming that $[0,1]$ is a closed subset of $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$. It isn't.

Comment: I assumed $[0,1]$ ,$[0,a]$ and $[b,1]$ are open sets because they are union of infinite opens.

Comment: How do you express, say, $[0,1]$ as the union of infinitely many elements of $\tau$? That's not possible. Every $O\in\tau$ such that $0\in O$ is such that $O\supset\mathbb{R}\setminus A$.

Comment: You were right, I had a fundamental mistake ,thanks for the solution, would it be possible a similar soloution for a generalised form of the problem?

Comment: @MasM Sure. What I did proves this: Given a topological space $(A,\tau)$ and a set $X$ such that $X\supset A$, it is possible to define a non-Hausdorff topology on $X$ which induces the topology $\tau$ on $A$ and such that the map $\iota\colon A\longrightarrow X$ defined by $\iota(x)=x$ is continuous.

Comment: What about the injectivity? In the main question we defined a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ then induced it to sets $A$ and $B$ , here we have just $X$ and $A$.

Comment: How can a map defined by $\iota(x)=x$ **not** be injective?